# Labels too long to show in chartjs Pie chart

Tags: label, chart.js, legend, legend-properties

I have below code for a chartjs Pie chart where few labels are too large to show on page when tapped by user.

**Code**

```
var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data:  values,
                backgroundColor: coloring,
                label: 'Dataset 1'
            }],
            labels: labels
        },
        options: {
            segmentShowStroke : false,
            animateScale : true,
            responsive: true
        }
    };
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        var myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Please find the screenshot when User taps on it.
[image]

Can someone please let me know if I can change the label position when tapped by User based on space available on screen or any other workaround to this issue.